# Creating a polygon around a "real estate" depending on my point "control" using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am new to GIS and trying to learn as much as I can. Currently, I am not able to understand how one specific project works.

**What I have**:

1. Layer "Controls"
2. layer "Base Map of the city" (With polygons!)

**What I want to do**: I want the polygon of the real estate to change color depending on the entry "date" of my point (layer control).

**Better:** I want a new layer, which creates a polygon matching the real estate outlines where my "control" layer sets a point. The new polygon should change color depending on the entry "date" of my point (layer control)

I'll leave a screenshot of how I would like it to be:

[image: 3 different points with 3 different dates color 3 different]

Comment: You have to work with the Layer 3 or a copy of it to detect if there is a "Control" point from Layer 1 and create your style (without forgetting the "no point" style). In QGIS expression, in geometry group, look for "contains" (https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=expression#contains).

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correct, you have a polygon and a point layer and you want to apply a different style to those polygons that contain a point. You can achieve this in the following way. If the question is another one, plese be more clear and edit the question.

On the point layer, use geometry generator ([see details here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814)) to create a new symbol layer with this expression (`polygon` is the name of the polygon layer):

```
array_first (overlay_within('polygon', $geometry))
```

Please remark that `overlay_within()` function is available since QGIS 3.16

*Screenshot: whenever you add a point, the polygon it is contained in will be highlighted:*
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to change the style of the polygon (layer "flur") depending on one field of the point layer ("layer kontrolle")? I want the polygon to change its color depending on the date of the last point made inside that polygon.